# How to get URL to refresh: ImportHTML not Pulling New Data in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that pulls golf scores using ImportHTML("http://www.augusta.com/masters/leaderboard","table",1) that I want to update every minute as scores are refreshed. I created a Google Apps Script trigger to run every minute. The trigger runs and it "refreshes"every minute, but it pulls the OLD DATA from the website and doesn't pull any of the new scores. How to I get it to pull the new scores?

I created a Google Apps Script trigger to run every minute (see code).

```
function getData() { 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AUGUSTA"); 
  var queryString = Math.random(); 
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("http://www.augusta.com/masters/leaderboard","table",1)';

    sheetName.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);
```

The trigger runs and it "refreshes"every minute, but it pulls the OLD DATA from the website and doesn't pull any of the new scores. The only way I can get it to update correctly is by manually entering the cell, and re-entering the URL (changing it slightly, then correcting it). How to I get it to pull the new scores?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Admittedly this is kind of a silly way to do this when you can just insert the formula in as a cell function.  But it's seems to like an easy way to get the data into an array.

```
function getGolfData() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.insertSheet(); 
  sh.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=IMPORTHTML("http://www.augusta.com/masters/leaderboard","table",1)');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  ss.deleteSheet(sh);
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Augusta');
  osh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[1].length).setValues(vA);
}
```